# How to derive the type of an applicator applied to the identity function

Tags: haskell, unification, hindley-milner

I want to derive the type of the following contrived applicator applied to the identity function. To achieve this I probably have to unify the type portion of the first argument `(a -> [b])` with the type of `id`:

```
ap :: (a -> [b]) -> a -> [b]
id :: a -> a

a -> [b]
a0 -> a0 -- fresh type vars

a ~ a0 -- mappings
[b] ~ a0

a0 -> a0 -- substitution
```

This is obviously wrong, since the expected type is `[b] -> [b]`. There is an ambiguity within the unification, because `a0` cannot be equivalent to both `a` and `[b]`, except for `a ~ [b]` . But what is the rule that tells me to substitute `a` with `[b]` and not the other way around, as I would have to do with `ap :: ([a] -> b) -> [a] -> b` for example.

I know this is a very specific question, sorry. Hopefully it is not too confusing!

Comment: What do you mean by "expected type is `[b] -> [b]`"? Why do you expect that?

Comment: I did `:t ap id` in GHCi with an `undefined` implementation for `ap`.

Comment: That tells you the type of  `ap` applied to `id`, not unified with `id`.

Comment: Oh, right. So I mean the unification of `a -> [b]` with `a -> a`, I guess. Sorry!

Comment: Ok, so..  That's an entirely different question.  You probably should edit your original question to clarify that. :)

Comment: Substitution always changes a variable to something else (which could be a variable again).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, new answer because I now understand the question being asked!  To restate the question:

Given

```
ap :: (a -> [b]) -> a -> [b]
id :: a -> a
```

Explain how the type of the expression `ap id` is derived.

Answer:

Rename variables:

```
ap :: (a -> [b]) -> a -> [b]
id :: a0 -> a0
```

Unify:

```
(a -> [b]) ~ (a0 -> a0)
```

Apply generativity a couple times, pulling the arguments from the `(->)` type constructor:

```
a   ~ a0
[b] ~ a0
```

Apply commutativity/transitivity of type equality:

```
[b] ~ a
```

Substitute the most specific types known into the types of `ap` and `id`

```
ap :: ([b] -> [b]) -> [b] -> [b]
id :: [b] -> [b]
```

`[b]` is the most specific type known, because it provides some restriction. The value must be a list of something.  The other two equivalent type expressions just mean any type at all.  You can think of unification as a constraint-solving process.  You find the maximal type that satisfies the constraints provided, which amount to "it's a list of something" for this case.

Now that the types are unified, the type of the function application is the type of the function's result:

```
ap id :: [b] -> [b]
```

I can see why the choice of `[b]` looks a little odd in this case, because only one of the three type expressions contributed factors to unify.  There are more involved cases where constraints come from multiple places, though.

Let's consider a more advanced case.  This might involve some things you haven't seen before.  If it does, I apologize for jumping straight to the deep end.

Given:

```
f1 :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
f2 :: p c d -> (e, c) -> (e, d)
```

Unify the types of `f1` and `f2`.

Let's be really careful with this one.  First up, rewrite all the types in terms of prefix application.  Even the `(->)` types.  This is going to be ugly:

```
f1 :: (->) ((->) a b) ((->) (f a) (f b))
f2 :: (->) (p c d) ((->) ((,) e c) ((,) e d))
```

Unify and apply generativity twice to top-level `(->)` type constructors:

```
((->) a b) ~ (p c d)
((->) (f a) (f b)) ~ ((->) ((,) e c) ((,) e d))
```

And, just keep unifying and applying generativity:

```
(->) ~ p
a ~ c
b ~ d
f a ~ (,) e c
f b ~ (,) e d
f ~ (,) e
```

Ok, we've built up a giant stack of constraints now.  Choosing between `a` and `c` or `b` and `d` doesn't matter, as they're equivalently constrained. Let's choose letters closer to the beginning of the alphabet when it doesn't matter.  `(->)` is more constrained than `p`, so it wins there, and `(,) e` is more constrained than `f`.  Call it a winner too.

Then switch back to infix type constructors to make it pretty, and the unified type is:

```
(a -> b) -> (e, a) -> (e, b)
```

Notice how each of the two starting types contributed a constraint to the final unified type. `f1` requires the `p` type in `f2` to be more specific, and `f2` required the `f` type in `f1` to be more specific.

Overall, this is a super-mechanical process.  It's also fiddly and requires precise tracking of what you know.  There's a reason we mostly leave it to the compiler to handle this.  It is absolutely useful in the cases when something goes wrong and you want to double-check the process yourself to see why the compiler is reporting an error, though.

Comment: @ftor absolutely. Basic Hindley-Milner type inference uses Algorithm W for unification. GHC goes beyond basic Hindley-Milner types in several ways, and so it uses a more complex algorithm. You can find publications by Simon Peyton Jones that describe different systems GHC has used over the years.  I believe the current algorithm is still based on [OutsideIn(X)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/jfp-outsidein.pdf) with some modifications as GHC has developed further.

Comment: Thanks for your time and for sharing your knowledge! I have made a big leap forward on this subject.